# After request vs after a request

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Of the below sentences, which is correct?

> On the new platform custom OEM syscalls are prohibited, support team
>   confirmed it after request.
>
> On the new platform custom OEM syscalls are prohibited, support team
>   confirmed it after a request.

Also, should I use definite article with support team when it's known what team I'm talking about? Can it be omitted in casual speech?

Comment: That last part requires a verb and maybe an object. Consider "The support team confirmed after I (...?)". it would probably look something like "..., support team confirmed it after **a** request *was sent to them/made* (last week)." If you don't want to use an object or verb, you can use "following": "support team confirmed it **following a request**."

Comment: On another note, you should indeed use "the" in before "support team", because support team is not a proper noun or a designation.

Answer (score 1):

Request is both a countable and uncountable noun.  You can say either "after a request" or "after request".  The request is used as an uncountable noun in the idioms on request, upon request, by request, etc.

The preposition "on" also means "immediately after; when something happens.
So, to be more idiomatic, you can use "on request" instead of "after a request".

The OP is right; he should use "the" in front of support team.

Comment: I'd say the "adverbial" usages *on request, upon request, by request* all mean exactly the same thing in typical contexts such as *Further details are available [preposition] request*, but (idiomatically, at least) no-one would ever use ***after a request*** in that context. I can't precisely pin down why it's the preferred choice in OP's specific context, but I think it's to do with the fact that we're reporting what happened after one specific request, rather than talking about the fact that the support team are able and willing to provide such confirmations as and when requested.